# -bash: emacs.profile: command not found

Tags: bash, emacs, command, profile

I am trying to resolve this issue and trying to get it work. What are all the steps of the solution? I really don't know what to do on my Mac terminal

```
-bash: emacs.profile: command not found
```

Comment: (Regarding your recently deleted question, that one is unlikely to fit on Stack Overflow - if you were to post the code with some example comments, then it would be so opinion-based that it would not work on a Q&A site).

Comment: This one is also off-topic because it is unclear what you are trying to do, there is no specific problem statement, and someone is unlikely to be able to reproduce the issue. I would advise you to stop posting questions from your account until you have read [ask] - too many closed questions will apply an automatic question ban on your account.

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to accomplish? If you're trying to open a file named `.profile` with emacs you'll want to add a space between the command `emacs` and the file `.profile`:

```
$ emacs .profile
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are typing `emacs.profile` you will get an error because you are mixing together the command `emacs` and the file you are trying to edit: `.profile`. Therefore the solution would be to add a space between them like someone suggested: `$ emacs .profile`.

On the other hand, if you are typing `emacs .profile` and you are still getting: `-bash: emacs: command not found`, this means that you haven't installed `emacs` yet and your system doesn't recognize that instruction.

**Emacs** is a very popular text editor and is widely used by technical users, but it is not installed by default.

**Solution 1:**

If you want to edit a file (in this case `~/.profile`) you don't need emacs to do so, you could just use a normal text editor or a pre-installed text editor using your terminal like:

`$ vi ~/.profile` or `$ nano ~/.profile`

([Guide to use Vi/Vim text editors](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-save-file-in-vim-quit-editor/)) ([Guide to use Nano](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Nano/Basics_Guide)).

**Solution 2:**

If you want to install emacs to edit that file, you can do so using brew:

```
$ brew update
$ brew install emacs
```

And after that you can use:

```
$ emacs ~/.profile
```

You can find other ways to install emacs [here](https://wikemacs.org/wiki/Installing_Emacs_on_OS_X).

**Important Note:**

One important thing to consider in this example, is that if you are trying to edit the `.profile` file (i.e. to set an exported environment variable) you should know that the name of the `.profile` file might vary from one Mac system to another. The name of this profile configuration file depends on the shell of your system, if you are using bash the name of this profile will be `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`.
Before editing your profile file make sure what is the name of the profile file you are trying to edit. To do so, you can use:

`$ cd $HOME`

to go to the Home folder and then use:

`$ ls -al`

to see hidden files (These files starting with `.` are hidden files). You will find the profile file of your system there.